# How to add search bar on dropdown(can choose Multiple box) list by using Infopath or Shapepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

How to add search bar on dropdown(can choose Multiple box) list in sharepoint?[image]

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath doesn’t support custom code or custom control, so you won’t be able to add a search bar in InfoPath form.

You may consider autocomplete function with multiple choice column.

Please see the reference below.

[Multiple Form Fields Autocomplete for SharePoint 2010/2013 using JavaScript.](https://sympmarc.com/2013/10/07/spservices-stories-17-multiple-form-fields-autocomplete-for-sharepoint-20102013-using-javascript/)